# Other properties of Legendre Polynomials

Tags: legendre-polynomials

Given the fact:
(Asymptotic form) For $\theta \in (0, \pi)$, we have
$$ P_n(\cos \theta)= J_0(n\theta)+ O(\dfrac{1}{n})= \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi n \sin \theta}}\sin \left(\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) + O(\dfrac{1}{n}),$$
(where $J_0$ is the zeroth Bessel function of the first kind). Consequently, for $x \in [-1,1]$ we get $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n(x) = 0.$

Prove that for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $n \geq 1$,
$$ (1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{4}} \lvert {P_n(x)} \rvert < \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{n \pi}}.$$

My approach:

Let $$x=\cos\theta$$.
$$ \implies x^2 = \cos^2 \theta$$
$$ \implies x^2 = 1 - \sin^2 \theta$$
$$ \implies sin^2 \theta = x^2 - 1$$
$$ \implies \sqrt{sin\theta}= (x^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$ \
Given,
$$ P_n(\cos \theta)= \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi n \sin \theta}}\sin \left(\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) + O(\dfrac{1}{n}),$$
$$ \sqrt{sin\theta}P_n(\cos \theta) = \sqrt{sin\theta}\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi n \sin \theta}}\sin \left(\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) + O(\dfrac{1}{n})$$
$$ \sqrt{sin\theta}P_n(\cos \theta) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi n }}\sin \left(\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) + O(\dfrac{1}{n})$$
$$ \sqrt{sin\theta}P_n(\cos \theta) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi n }}\sin \left(\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) + O(\dfrac{1}{n})$$
$$ (x^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}P_n(\cos \theta) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi n }}\sin \left(\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) + O(\dfrac{1}{n})$$

Since $\sin \left(\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$ is bounded between -1 and 1 with a max value of 1, and $ O(\dfrac{1}{n})$ is an error which is negligible, how would $ (1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{4}} \lvert {P_n(x)} \rvert < \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{n \pi}}.$?
Isn't it $ (1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{4}} \lvert {P_n(x)} \rvert \leq \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{n \pi}}.$ instead?

Comment: The inequality cannot be proved from the asymptotics. The asymptotics is used to show that the constant $\frac{2}{\pi}$ is the best possible. Consider Section 7.3 in Szegő's Orthogonal Polynomials.